# Harry Potter Kata

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net-core

I have implemented the Harry Potter Kata and I need your feedbacks.

The rules are:

A book costs 8 euros. There are 5 different volumes. To get a discount, you must buy books of different volumes:

- Buying 1 book doesn't give you a discount
- Buying 2 books applies a 5% discount
- Buying 3 books applies a 10% discount
- Buying 4 books applies a 15% discount
- Buying 5 books applies a 20% discount

Examples:

- Given a basket When I buy 2 books of volume 1 Then the total is 16 euros
- Given a basket When I buy 1 book of volume 1 And I buy 1 book of volume 2 Then the total is 15.2 euros

The implementation:

```
 public class Book
    {
        public double Price { get; } = 8;
        public string Volume { get; }

        public Book(string volume)
        {
            Volume = volume;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            // Is null?
            if (obj is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Is the same object?
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Is the same type?
            return obj.GetType() == this.GetType() && IsEqual((Book)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Price, Volume);
        }

        private bool IsEqual(Book book)
        {
            // A pure implementation of value equality that avoids the routine checks above
            // We use String.Equals to really drive home our fear of an improperly overridden "=="
            return string.Equals(Volume, book.Volume)
                   && Equals(Price, book.Price);
        }
    }



     public class Basket
        {
            private readonly IDictionary<int, IDiscountStrategy> _discountStrategies;
            private readonly IList<HashSet<Book>> _bookSets;

            public Basket(IDictionary<int, IDiscountStrategy> discountStrategies)
            {
                _discountStrategies = discountStrategies;
                _bookSets = new List<HashSet<Book>>();
            }

            public void AddBook(Book book)
            {
                var setIndex = 0;
                var inserted = false;

                while (!inserted)
                {
                    if (_bookSets.Count <= setIndex) _bookSets.Add(new HashSet<Book>());

                    if (!_bookSets[setIndex].Contains(book) && _bookSets[setIndex].Count < _discountStrategies.Count)
                    {
                        _bookSets[setIndex].Add(book);
                        inserted = true;
                    }
                    setIndex++;
                }
            }

            public double Checkout() => _bookSets.Sum(set =>
                    GetTotalCostBeforeDiscount(set) * _discountStrategies[set.Count].GetDiscount());

            private double GetTotalCostBeforeDiscount(IEnumerable<Book> books) => books.Sum(b => b.Price);
        }

 public class FifteenPercentDiscount : IDiscountStrategy
    {
        public double GetDiscount() => .85;
    }
 public class FivePercentDiscount : IDiscountStrategy
    {
        public double GetDiscount() => .95;
    }
 public class NoDiscount : IDiscountStrategy
    {
        public double GetDiscount() => 1;
    }
 public class TenPercentDiscount : IDiscountStrategy
    {
        public double GetDiscount() => .9;
    }
public class TwentyPercentDiscount : IDiscountStrategy
    {
        public double GetDiscount() => 0.8;
    }
    public interface IDiscountStrategy
    {
        double GetDiscount();
    }

public class BookTest
    {
        private readonly Basket _basket;
        public BookTest()
        {
            var discountStrategies = new Dictionary<int, IDiscountStrategy>
            {
                {1, new NoDiscount() },
                {2, new FivePercentDiscount() },
                {3, new TenPercentDiscount() },
                {4, new FifteenPercentDiscount() },
                {5, new TwentyPercentDiscount() },
            };
            _basket = new Basket(discountStrategies);

        }
        [Fact]
        public void should_book_price_equals_to_8_when_created()
        {   //arrange
            var book = new Book("Volume 1");
            var expected = 8;
            //act
            var actual = book.Price;
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void should_two_books_price_equals_to_16_when_they_have_the_same_volume()
        {
            //arrange 
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            var expected = 16;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void should_have_five_percent_discount_when_two_books_books_do_not_have_the_same_volume()
        {
            //arrange 
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 2"));
            var expected = 16 * .95;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void should_have_ten_percent_discount_when_three_books_do_not_have_the_same_volume()
        {
            //arrange 
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 2"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            var expected = 24 * .90;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void should_have_fifteen_percent_discount_when_four_books_do_not_have_the_same_volume()
        {
            //arrange 
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 2"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 4"));
            var expected = 32 * .85;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void should_have_twenty_percent_discount_when_four_books_do_not_have_the_same_volume()
        {
            //arrange
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 2"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 4"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 5"));
            var expected = 40 * .8;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void should_have_ten_percent_discount_when_three_books_do_not_have_the_same_volume_and_no_discount_for_the_last_book()
        {
            //arrange 
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 2"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            var expected = (24 * .9) + 8;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
        [Fact]
        public void should_have_ten_percent_discount_when_three_books_do_not_have_the_same_volume_and_no_discount_for_the_last_two_books()
        {
            //arrange 
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 2"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            var expected = (24 * .9) + 16;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void should_create_three_sets_and_the_max_size_of_a_set_equal_to_the_number_of_strategies_to_not_get_KeyNotFoundException()
        {
            //arrange 
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 1"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 2"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 3"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 4"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 5"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 6"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 7"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 8"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 9"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 10"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 11"));
            _basket.AddBook(new Book("Volume 11"));
            var expected = (40 * .8) + (40 * .8) + 16;
            //act
            var actual = _basket.Checkout();
            //assert
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi ilyes, I am not such skilled to do full code review, however I have a few comments that might help you. The `Checkout()` method has two lines. I would use old style of method with curly braces instead of `=>`. I would rename `Checkout()` method to something more self-explanatory, e.g. `GetTotalCostAfterDiscount()` or `_basket.Calculate()`. In your first test method, I would check one book basket calculation with the same concept as used in all other tests. When reading this lambda `.Sum(set =>` I was firstly confused, that set is some keyword. I would use `s =>`. I like your solution!

Comment: @TomasPaul Please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). (hint: you can possibly earn more reputation that way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to work with immutable classes. Most of your namings are clear.

## Algorithm

It took me a while to understand the logic. I understand that the algorithm is: dividing the books to groups where each group doesn't contain the same volume twice and has a max size of 5. Create larger groups as possible in order to maximize the discount.

I would add this description as a comment.

The function responsible for the dividing should be called something like `DivideToUniqeVolumeGroups`.

### Pseudo Code

Here is a pseudo-code of your algorithm:

For each book:

1. Find a non-full group which doesn't contain a book with a given volume
2. If such group don't exists create a new group
3. Add the book to the group

I think writing the code to be similar to the pseudo-code above will be much more readable.

## Hidden Assumptions

You are looking for a group that doesn't contain a specific volume, but in code you use `!_bookSets[setIndex].Contains(book)`. **It is not clear**. It is working because all books have the same price and it has only those 2 properties. Once something will change it will **stop working**.

## Naming

Usually in shopping systems what you called basket is called a cart.

I like to name a Dictionary with a  name that explains what is the key and what is the value. In that case `booksCount2discount`.

## Strategy Design Pattern

The strategy should get a books list in order to create logic depending on the books.

I think that the strategy design pattern is a bit over-engineering in this case because the logic is always the same: applying a discount according to the books count. I think a dictionary between the books count and the discount value is sufficient.

You created a class for each discount value. Don't need for all those classes, replace it with a single class that accepts the discount value as a parameter in a constructor. This way the discounts can be configurable.

It is more clear if the strategy returns the discount value. (0.1 for 10% discount)

## Code

### Basket

Move the logic from `AddBook` to `Checkout`. I think it is more clear that way. Also, you will not need `_bookSets`.

Creating a class for a group called `UniqeVolumeGroup` will add to readability. Adding validations will help to find bugs faster.

I think `GetTotalCostBeforeDiscount` is unnecessary since the code is quite clear and shorter than the function name.

### Book

Don't set the price inside Book.

## Tests

You are using a class member `_basket` in all the tests. Depending on the testing framework, this could lead to **tests affecting each other** when running in **parallel**. I would create a new basket for each test.

`should_create_three_sets_and_the_max_size_of_a_set_equal_to_the_number_of_strategies_to_not_get_KeyNotFoundException`
This name is too technical because it mentions strategies and exceptions. **You should name the tests in terms of the domain.** I would call the test something like group size should not be greater than max books at a discount.

Answer (score 4):

Some people have already pointed out important points, particularly the use of `Decimal` for money values.

Higher-level stuff:

- You have some white-space inconsistencies.
- Having the basket start with a batch of possibly applicable discounts doesn't make much sense. The basket can more-or-less just be a list until the time comes to calculate discounts. Hopefully this ends up being less verbose.
- In general, a little less verbosity would be nice. `Book.Equals` for example could be single `and` block.
- Instead of having `Basket.AddBook`, I would prefer to construct the baskets with books already in them. In the simplest case, `public Basket(params IEnumerable<Book> book_lists){...}` would allow a lot of flexibility including merging existing baskets. In general, one usually can and should avoid changing the state of objects.
- While building a dictionary in which to look up discount strategies is efficient, it's not what I would want to see in production code; it's too limiting. **I've worked with a couple different "discount" paradigms, and it's a good idea to build in flexibility early on.** *If* you get it right, then it's simpler in the long run than adding complexity as you go. Some common patterns:

  - A discount object should be able to inspect the basket and report if it can be applied.
    `public bool Applicable(Basket basket){...}`
  - Can multiple discounts apply? Will this ever depend on *which* discounts *might* apply? Have a system for figuring this out.
  - Discount objects should have a property (often just an int, whatever) to denote the order in which they should apply (for example `0.9 * (x - 5)` is different from `(0.9 * x) - 5`).

Answer (score 2):

First off, anything pertaining to money or currency should use `Decimal` instead of `Double`.  `Decimal` is a base-10 floating point for exact decimal places, whereas `Double` is an approximation.

`Book` class should implement `IEquatable<Book>`.

The discount strategies should be static or overall strategies independent of any given `Basket`.  Perhaps this would even be in a separate class.  When you later calculate what's in a given `Basket`, you would then lookup and apply the appropriate strategy based on the `Basket` contents at that given point in time.

Comment: Bump for `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to put just few recommendation or considerations, not full code review evaluating design patterns or functional issues.

- The `Checkout()` method has two lines. I would use old method body style with curly braces instead of expression body defnition with lambda operator `=>`.
- I would rename `Checkout()` method to something more self-explanatory, e.g. `GetTotalCostAfterDiscount()` or `_basket.Calculate()`.
- In your first test method, I would check one book basket calculation with the same concept as used in all other tests. Or you can add test with no added books (boundary value tests).
- When reading this lambda `.Sum(set =>` I was firstly confused, that `set` is some keyword. I would personally use `s =>`.

I like your solution, I cannot see any major issues. It is neat, following SOLID principles and naming conventions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tomas,thanks for your feedback, I appreciate it :).